# Angular Dialog with Angular Form

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have an Angular app and am using Angular-Material among other components.
Is it possible to open an Angular Tab Dialog with a TemplateUrl being lazy loaded which contains an Angular form?
How would you reference this form if at all possible?
Here is some code I use to open the dialog:

```
    $scope.showTabDialog = function(ev) {

        $mdDialog.show({
                controller: DialogController,
                templateUrl: 'pages/properties/tabDialog.tmpl.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose:true
            })
            .then(function(answer) {
                $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
            }, function() {
                $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
            });
    };
```

Any Help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: so what's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question correctly but for basic use, pass in your context to `locals` and return your info to `$mdDialog.hide`

```
    $mdDialog.show({
      targetEvent: $event,
      template: dialogContent,
      controller: 'DialogController',
      locals: { info: $scope.info }
    }).then(function(info) {
        if(info) {
          $scope.info.userName = info.userName;      
        }
      });
```

...

```
$mdDialog.hide(info);
```

See this Code Pen:

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjqzJR

Comment: @johan did that answer your question?

Comment: Hi guys, please accept my apologies for late reply, i have been working on another project and have only been able to come back to this problem now. I think this is exactly what I need and I will test your answer with my project. Thank you, I will revert if it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, you sent me in the right direction. It is working now

Comment: Ah, I'm stuck now binding the info variable to the form elements inside the dialog box